# Good alternative for ant for use on jenkins build server

Tags: ant, build, continuous-integration, jenkins

Hy there. I have a number of software projects (also iOS and OSX) which I build with [Apache ant](http://ant.apache.org/)`.

Although I quite like Ant it is often too verbose and some things which should be easy are quite tricky or I have to use shell scripts along with ant.

Is there a good alternative for which is extensible, easy to use and should work well on my jenkins build server.

Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/) - it's quite different from Ant and may take a little while to get your head around, but I think it's going to be the new standard for build systems.  One nice thing is that it has full Ant support under the hood, so you can easily get your existing Ant builds running and then port them to Gradle.

Answer (score 1):

Gareth's answer of Gradle is a good one. But do take a look at what you are doing that is hard with Ant. In my experience, a fair portion of the time its "non-build" stuff. Perhaps leave Ant for the pure build stuff, and use an alternate tool for and deploy or test stuff that's snuck in there.

Answer (score 1):

Although gradle looks very promising I decided to use [Rake](http://rake.rubyforge.org/) instead.

I should say that this is a biased decision since I am already using ruby for other parts in my build setup. I found a good [Article by Martin Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/articles/rake.html)

Another point is that by doing OSX development the platform-independence-aspect of Ant (or Gradle) does not have such a big weight for me.

Answer (score 1):

BTW Besi's Rake answer:
JRuby's Rake+Ant integration seems like a really powerful combo:

http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2010/rake-and-ant-together-a-pick-it-n-stick-it-approach

One big advantange there, it fully supports integration with Ant, allowing step-by-step migration.. which IMHO is only viable strategy for large, existing projects.

Gradle seems similar and while it looks good; I think learning Rake could be a better investment as it's more universal outside of Java.

(The other thing I'm seriously considering is BuildR http://buildr.apache.org, but Jenkins doens't explicitly support it *yet*, so have to use scripted build steps, which seems less preferable. TODO: a BuildR plugin).